# Can $\log_{10}{x}, \ln(x), x$ form a geometric sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, geometric-series

Does there exists a unique value of $x$, if any, such that $\log_{10}{x}, \ln(x), x$ forms a geometric sequence in some order?

This also might seem like a very odd question, since I can't see an immediate relationship between raising $10$ to something to get $x$ and doing the same but with $e$ to get $x$.

Comment: Tried comparing graphs of $x/\ln(x)$ and $\ln(x)/\log_{10}(x)$ to see if they cross, looks like not.

Comment: Note that $\frac {\ln(x)}{\log_{10}x}=\ln(10) \approx 2.30$ is a constant.  You are then asking for a solution to $x=\ln(10) \cdot \ln(x)$.  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3Dlog%2810%29*log%28x%29) does not find any real solutions.

Comment: Furthermore, to check number of solution of the equation $\ln x=\frac{x}{\ln10}$ see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3733492/how-many-roots-does-ln-x-ax-have-depending-on-a?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Ross's comment, we want a real solution to $\ln(x)/x=1/\ln(10).$ The right side is greater than $0.4,$ while the max over positive reals of the left side occurs at $x=e$ and is $1/e=0.3678\cdots$ so no real solution.